# When people say "I am waiting on God." Are they afraid to take action in their own lives?

Tags: free-will, will-of-god, lifestyle, life

When people say "I am waiting on God." Are they afraid to take action in their own lives?

I have heard so many people in the church claim that they know the will of God, and what God's will is for my life. How do we know if this is legitimate or someone simply trying to further their own agenda?

If we are thankful for what we have, we will never set goals or try to improve ourselves or try to solve various problems within society?

How do we know when God truly intervenes?

Comment: Like any library, Christianity Stack Exchange offers great information, but does not offer personalized advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from your pastor, priest, or other trustworthy counselor.

Comment: There are many books on how to discern God's will in your life, and how to tell false leading from true. Buy you should start by talking to a Christian leader in your church.

Comment: I never stated I was looking for personalized advice anywhere in my question. Please take the time to read the entire question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bible serves as a guide for Christian living (2 Timothy 3:16). For example, helping others is God's command, but you still need God's intervention to know WHOM to help. It says in the Bible that you should love your enemies. There is still a question of who, where, when, and how. This is where the Holy Spirit comes in. You ask God for His leading. If God wants you to improve yourself, He will give signs and make it obvious what to do. Personally, I always pray for God's wisdom because God IS wisdom (1 Corinthians 1:24). If God is in you, you're always right, for God is perfect and in control. You have nothing to worry about (1 Peter 5:7, Proverbs 3:5-6).